# How to find and download a specific macOS update name that usually is not available within the apple download website

Tags: macos, mojave, dmg, package-management

Every time Apple release a minor macOS X update, for example (Supplemental, or Combo, or Security Update, etc), I usually visit https://support.apple.com/en_US/downloads and I download the dmg file and I push the package to all my Mac(s) and I am good to go.

But sometimes I am having issue in searching for a specific update that Apple released.

I give you a practical example:

Using the link that I provided you above, how do I find and download one of these two packages?  I tried to type in a different way but nothing is coming up.  Of course I can type macOS Supplemental Update 10.14.6 but the result is not what I am looking for.

```
Safari14.0.1MojaveAuto-14.0.1
    Safari (14.0.1), 67518K [recommended]
   * Safari14.0MojaveAuto-10.14.6
    macOS Supplemental Update (10.14.6), 67310K [recommended] [restart]
```

Thank you.

Comment: A Google search for "macOS Supplemental Update (10.14.6)" found this - https://support.apple.com/HT201222 - but I think there is a way to do this from commend line these days… I just don't know it ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks but yeah it is not the same.